# Object doesn't support this property or method: Workbooks.Worksheets.Range

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to duplicate color from a different workbook but getting a run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method on the last line. I believe that before setting the workbooks and worksheet to certain names, it worked. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub TextColor()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb1 = Workbooks("File 1.xlsm")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("File 2.xlsm")
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet 1")

wb2.Worksheets("Destination Sheet").Range("G4").Interior.Color = wb1.ws1.Range("D19").Interior.Color
```

Comment: `Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet 1")`... then change `wb1.ws1` to just `ws1`.

Answer (score 0):

The object 'ws1' is created separately and, while a child object of 'wb1', the variable itself is not a child object of it, only the reference to it. Valid referencing styles would be:

```
ws1
wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Also, when you set 'ws1' you should reference the parent workbook in that line. This would change your 'ws1' line to now be:

```
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

From then on you only need to reference 'ws1' as the object.

As a side note, when working with other workbooks, I recommend testing if the worksheet exists or not. If you hard-code the name in and it doesn't exist, gets changed, or you made a typing error, this can throw an error. Below is a function you can use to test if a worksheet exists or not.

```
Function WorksheetExists( _
         ByVal SheetName As String, _
         Optional TargetBook As Workbook _
         ) As Boolean

    If TargetBook Is Nothing Then
        If ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set TargetBook = ActiveWorkbook
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = CBool(Len(TargetBook.Worksheets(SheetName).Name) <> 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

The same logic applies if you're looking for a workbook and need to know if it exists, although a function for it would be slightly different, shown in the below code.

```
Public Function ExistingFile( _
       ByVal FilePath As String _
       ) As Boolean

    Dim Attributes As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    Attributes = GetAttr(FilePath)
    ExistingFile = (Err.Number = 0) And (Attributes And vbDirectory) = 0
    Err.Clear

End Function
```

Note the above function could potentially throw an error if the file name is too long.